# Sampling on NetworkX maintaining global characteristics

Tags: python, networkx

I have a huge graph on NetworkX, 1M+ edges.
I am able to compute the global statistics on the graph, e.g. degree distribution, average clustering, diameter, centrality, etc.

I would like to create a sample of this graph while maintaining its the global characteristics.

Is there an easy way to implement this in NetworkX?

Comment: There are algorithms for reshuffling edges that maintain degree distribution and one additional property, mostly the local clustering coefficient. However, you will not find an algorithm that preserves all global statistics. Trivially, you could come up with an infinite number of global statistics such that any local modification would always result in a change in some measure.